# use of the 'SHELL' environment variable

Tags: macos

I'm on OSX. I recently starting using the fish shell. I've noticed that

```
echo $SHELL
```

still gives me back

```
/bin/bash
```

even after I've set up Terminal to use the fish shell, and while executing the command from within said fish shell. (The path to the fish shell is `/usr/local/bin/fish`.) In the same vein, if I run the python program

```
import os
print(os.environ['SHELL'])
```

from within the fish shell I get back `/bin/bash` as the output, not `/usr/local/bin/fish`.

So I'm wondering, what is the relevance of the SHELL environment variable, if it doesn't show me the type of the current shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code of BASH, the `$SHELL` environment variable is set up to return the user's default shell. This is retrieved from the user's profile (`/etc/passwd`, if you will).

Python is just returning the environment variables that its parent (bash or fish) provided to it, so this isn't the fault of Python/Perl/etc.

That being said, if you want to find out what shell you are actually using, the recommended way is to look at the special variable `$0` which should return you something like `-bash` or `/usr/local/bin/fish`. However, that will only work from within the shell itself as Python/Perl/etc will presumably return their interpreter path instead.

So what is the purpose of the variable? It's a UNIX thing - if you create a session, this is reflecting what has been set as the default program that the OS will run and attach to your session at login and handle STDIN/STDOUT. This default program becomes the parent for everything you launch from there.

Yes, you could technically make this anything but sh/ksh/bash/zsh/fish is typical, though it isn't unusual to set it to something that prints a "No interactive shell allowed" and quit in environments where admins don't want shell access. But that being said, if you want it to default to fish instead, you need to set that up in the user account.

Comment: Inspecting the $0 variable from within python I find `/bin/sh` no matter which shell I run the python from. Inside the shell itself, the $0 variable seems not to exist in the fish shell, though it expands to `-bash`in the bash shell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Python is using the shell listed for your user in /etc/passwd. I don't know where that equivalent is on Mac. Even though the terminal is using fish, your user entry might still have bash listed.
Example:

```
samuel:x:1000:1000:Samuel:/home/samuel:/bin/bash
```

gives me '/bin/bash' from python.

```
samuel:x:1000:1000:Samuel:/home/samuel:/usr/bin/zsh
```

gives me '/usr/bin/zsh' from python.

You'll have to log out or restart your system for the change to be effective.